# What is a "gigamem"?

Tags: taocp

I am reading Donald Knuth's TAOCP: volume 4, Fascicle 6, p18.

He mentions the word **gigamem**.
What does he mean? What is a gigamem?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the index and glossary if you don't understand a specific term:

> Gigamems = billions of memory accesses